# What is used as a KEY and MESSAGE when using HMAC within a PBKDF2?

Tags: authentication, hmac, pbkdf-2, password-hashing

I was studying WPA2 and it's security when I came across this problem. I know that WPA2 uses PBKDF2 to generate a Pairwise Master Key. It does something like this;

```
DK = PBKDF2(prf=HMAC-SHA1, key=password, salt=ssid, DkLen=64, iterations=4096).
```

I get that. But what I don't is the PRF module itself. HMAC itself is `h(k + h(k+m))`
So, The rest of the part I get, but within the HMAC,

- What goes in as the KEY and the MESSAGE?
- Are both the same?
- if not what are they?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encryption algorithm used in WPA/WPA2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/28975/encryption-algorithm-used-in-wpa-wpa2). If the answer does not satisfy you. Let us know.

Comment: Sure, but that duplicate doesn't quite explain which one is the key or the message

Comment: `In PBKDF2 the binary password is used as key to the HMAC function. The salt is the SSID of the Wi-Fi connection. The salt + a counter value is used as the initial input to the HMAC function.` This is quite clear from that answer. `m = initial input` and `key = binary password`

Comment: Thanks Kelalaka. Got it right this time. Thanks a lot