# WPA/WPA password algorithm

Tags: algorithm-design, password-based-encryption, wpa2-psk

I would like to understand the mechanism behind wpa/wpa2 algorithm. Is there any script that can put this theory:(Key = PBKDF2(HMAC−SHA1, passphrase, ssid, 4096, 256)) into action to test it ? I made a capture of my own router with all necessary details, 
should this default Wifi password  be the Key in this equation?

[image: wpa default password]

Comment: Is there anything particular missing from [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/28981/1172)? I saw a recent upvote, but I don't know if that was you... Note that software recommendations are off topic here (there is [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site for that).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes this is rather a question and i posted it by mistake in another previous thread. I am not asking for software recommendations, it is just a simple script to put that theory into action and see if i get the same default password labeled on the router.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The password is the pass*phrase* in the equation, not the key. To test it you need to authenticate against the router. But implementing WPA is a bit more than just a script.